# How to install pip for Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, installation

I'd like to start by pointing out that this question may seem like a duplicate, but it isn't. All the questions I saw here were regarding pip for Python 3 and I'm talking about Python 3.6. The steps used back then don't work for Python 3.6.

1. I got a clear Ubuntu 16.10 image from the [official docker store](https://store.docker.com/images/414e13de-f1ba-40d0-9867-08f2e5884b3f).
2. Run `apt-get update`
3. Run `apt-get install python3.6`
4. Run `apt-get install python3-pip`
5. Run `pip3 install requests bs4`
6. Run `python3.6 script.py`

Got `ModuleNotFoundError` below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "script.py", line 6, in <module>
     import requests
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Python's and pip's I have in the machine:

```
python3
python3.5
python3.5m
python3.6
python3m
python3-config
python3.5-config
python3.5m-config
python3.6m
python3m-config  

pip
pip3
pip3.5
```

Comment: try downloading and running https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have a system running Ubuntu 16.04, 16.10, or 17.04, and you want Python 3.6 to be the default Python.

If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, you'll need to use a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6  # (only for 16.04 LTS)
```

Then, run the following (this works out-of-the-box on 16.10 and 17.04):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.6
sudo apt install python3.6-dev
sudo apt install python3.6-venv
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip3

# Do this only if you want python3 to be the default Python
# instead of python2 (may be dangerous, esp. before 2020):
# sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python
```

When you have completed all of the above, each of the following shell commands should indicate `Python 3.6.1` (or a more recent version of Python 3.6):

```
python --version   # (this will reflect your choice, see above)
python3 --version
$(head -1 `which pip` | tail -c +3) --version
$(head -1 `which pip3` | tail -c +3) --version
```

Comment: I believe it should be `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3.6 /usr/local/bin/pip3`, as `pip3` defaults to the default pip3.x installed on the system.

Comment: In the example that I've provided, pip is installed via `sudo python3.6 get-pip.py` as `/usr/local/bin/pip` and is aliased to `/usr/local/bin/pip3`. There is no `/usr/local/bin/pip3.6` on the system.

Comment: Oh ok. I get it now. Created one Ubuntu Server 17.04 for testing and out-of-the-box it comes with Python 3.5.x only, nothing regarding Python 2.x and no `pip` installed. After `apt install python3.6 / -dev / -env` I get Python 3.6.x, but `python3` symlink continues to point to the default Python 3.5.x as expected. Then a simple `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python` takes care of it. Then wget get-pip.py and run with `python` (Python 3.6.x after the symlink) and it's done. Marked yours as the correct anwser now, because it feels cleaner than the older.

Comment: fwiw, [pep 0394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) doesn't suggest the following: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/#recommendation) says "The more general `python` command should be installed whenever any version of Python 2 is installed and should invoke the same version of Python as the `python2` command". It could be dangerous to link `python3.6` to `python` on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Edited the original answer per the two comments above.

Comment: I needed to run sudo apt-get install python3-distutils too.

Comment: I did all of the above, and i am getting python 3.6 when i run `python3 --version` but i still get python3.5 when i run `$(head -1 `which pip3` | tail -c +3) --version`

Answer (score 36):

In at least in ubuntu 16.10, the default `python3` is `python3.5`.  As such, all of the `python3-X` packages will be installed for python3.5 and not for python3.6.

You can verify this by checking the shebang of `pip3`:

```
$ head -n1 $(which pip3)
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Fortunately, the pip installed by the `python3-pip` package is installed into the "shared" `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` such that python3.6 can also take advantage of it.

You can install packages for python3.6 by doing:

```
python3.6 -m pip install ...
```

For example:

```
$ python3.6 -m pip install requests
$ python3.6 -c 'import requests; print(requests.__file__)'
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py
```

Comment: @Anthony Sottile, Any suggestion on how to make python 3.6 default?

Comment: One way to make python3.6 the default for pip is to make an executable which is named "pip" but essentially does `exec python3.6 -m pip` -- throw that in `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.  Replacing the operating system default `python3` executable is not suggested and will lead to OS instability.

Comment: "No module named pip" When I try this.

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute do you have `python-pip` installed (via `apt`)?

Comment: Anthony - yes. _

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute from testing, that probably means you ran (at some point) `sudo pip install pip --upgrade`, this will move pip to the py35 dist-packages.  You can probably get the old one back with `sudo apt install --reinstall python-pip` or use `get-pip.py` with python3.6 as suggested in the comments above

Comment: That sounds like something I may have done. Thanks; I'll try that once I get Ubuntu reinstalled; I think I somehow broke the login screen beyond repair while troubleshooting this :/

Answer (score 12):

This answer assumes that you have `python3.6` installed. For `python3.7`, replace `3.6` with `3.7`. For `python3.8`, replace `3.6` with `3.8`, but it may also first require the `python3.8-distutils` package.

### Installation with sudo

With regard to [installing `pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/), using `curl` (instead of `wget`) avoids writing the file to disk.

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo -H python3.6
```

The `-H` flag is evidently necessary with `sudo` in order to prevent errors such as the following when installing pip for an updated python interpreter:

> The directory '/home/someuser/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory
>   is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.
>   Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing
>   pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> The directory
>   '/home/someuser/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the
>   current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the
>   permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo,
>   you may want sudo's -H flag.

### Installation without sudo

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.6 - --user
```

This may sometimes give a warning such as:

> WARNING: The script wheel is installed in '/home/ubuntu/.local/bin'
>   which is not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if
>   you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

### Verification

After this, `pip`, `pip3`, and `pip3.6` can all be expected to point to the same target:

```
$ (pip -V && pip3 -V && pip3.6 -V) | uniq
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

Of course you can alternatively use `python3.6 -m pip` as well.

```
$ python3.6 -m pip -V
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This website contains a much cleaner solution, it leaves pip intact as-well and one can easily switch between 3.5 and 3.6 and then whenever 3.7 is released.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

A short summary:

```
sudo apt-get install python python-pip python3 python3-pip
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2
```

Then

```
$ pip -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
$ pip3 -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

Then to select python 3.6 run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

and select '2'. Then

```
$ pip3 -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

To update pip select the desired version and

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip

$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please note. Currently the python package "apt_pkg" is not yet available from pip in python 3.6, meaning that some commands such as "apt-add-repository" might not work.

Comment: On Ubuntu, Python 3 is tightly integrated with the OS, so different versions are not alternatives, and you shouldn't change the symlink `/usr/bin/python3`. So this could easily cause problems. E.g. [your terminal might not open](https://askubuntu.com/q/880188/301745).

Answer (score 3):

Some of the solutions above using the script `get-pip.py` worked until a couple of weeks ago.

The latest version of this script now requires `python3.7` throwing the following error

```
ERROR: This script does not work on Python 3.6 
The minimun supported Python version is 3.7. 
Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py instead.
```

So making the corresponding change works now.

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
```