# How to install PIP on Python 3.6?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to Install PIP for python 3.6 and I've looked over YouTube for tutorials but all of them seem to be out of date and none of them have seemed to work. Any information would be helpful so I can carry on with my project.

Comment: Please add which method have you tried exactly, and which particular error you have faced.

Comment: `pip` should be bundled with 3.6.  Check  the `bin` directory in your distribution, alternatively try `pip3`.

Comment: Why are you under the impression that it needs to be installed?

Comment: pip is already installed if you're using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 binaries downloaded from python.org

Comment: i have tried using the get-pip.py method i also tried using the pip that is bundled in the python package but none of it seems to work

Comment: Pip is installed by default. In Windows  If you are getting an error in command prompt saying that it's not recognised as a command then you must add it to your path.

Comment: Scripts folder under python installation folder is empty after I installed python3.6 on windows.

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`pip` is bundled with Python > 3.4

**On Unix-like systems use:**

```
python3.6 -m pip install [Package_to_install]
```

**On a Windows system use:**

```
py -m pip install [Package_to_install]
```

(On Windows you may need to run the command prompt as administrator to be able to write into python installation directory)

Comment: You can actually create an alias for each installed python version and call it like the regular `pip`,i.e.: for python3.6  `alias pip3.6="python3.6 -m pip"` which can be called like `pip3.6 install pandas` or for python3 `alias pip3="python3 -m pip"` then `pip3 install pandas`, etc

Comment: Not always! [leonardo@localhost ~]$ python3.6 -m pip install pip
/usr/bin/python3.6: No module named pip

Comment: When I type: python3.6 -m pip install pip I get: /usr/bin/python3.6: No module named pip

Comment: Agree with @llazzaro. I get the `python3.6 -m pip install pip /usr/bin/python3.6: No module named pip` treatment. To fix the error, you need to manually install pip as [Will I Am](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141516/will-i-am) pointed out in his [message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51047189/2402281):
`wget -qO- https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3.6`

Comment: I installed python 3.6 and 3.7 but still get no pip ! scripts folder under python installation folder is empty.

Comment: pip is NOT always bundled with Python. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: how about using apt like `apt-get install python-pip`?

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer, it does not answer the question asked. The question is 'how to install pip', this answer shows how to install a package with pip, which (as many have commented) is not always installed as standard with python anyway.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47123768/6284028; Jim fixed this issue.

Answer (score 66):

Download python 3.6

It is possible that pip does not get installed by default. One potential fix is to open cmd and type:

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

and then

```
python -m pip install [Package_to_install]
```

actually i had nothing in my scripts folder idk why
but these steps  worked for me.

Comment: This is the one that worked; for some reason the EPEL release on CENTOS 7 doesn't allow you to install additional packages for PIP, but since pip is a separate release cycle, this allows you to bootstrap it even without internet. Amazing fix; thank you!

Comment: This gives `/usr/bin/python3.6: No module named ensurepip`

Comment: After running this and then trying to run this `python3.6 -m pip list` I get `Violación de segmento (`core' generado)`

Comment: Fix for my comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376525/segmentation-fault-while-installing-python-3-5-ensurepip/1377190#1377190

Answer (score 27):

If pip doesn't come with your installation of python 3.6, this may work:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
```

then you can python -m install

Comment: I get this `AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'`

Comment: This script now requires python 3.7 or greater unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

pip is included in Python installation. If you can't call pip.exe try calling python -m pip [args] from cmd

Comment: There are cases where python installation doesn't include a pip. Mine was 3.6.5 and there were no pip package

Comment: I am using WSL Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on Windows 10. 
I have python 3.6.9, but no pip

Comment: @KartikPodugu WSL is very minimal, install the python3-pip package

Answer (score 9):

How did you install Python, and are you using a virtual environment?
As you specifically mentioned Python 3.6, and you have not marked this as answered I will make a guess that you might have installed it using [sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6), as this is a common way to install Python 3.6 on a Unix OS that doesn't have a native 3.6 package.  If this is the case the correct way to install pip is as follows ....

Step 1) Make a Virtual Environment with Python 3.6 ...

```
python3.6 -m venv env --without-pip
```

Step 2) Activate your virtual environemnt ...

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Step 3) Install pip into your environemnt ...

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
```

Answer (score 9):

I Used these commands in Centos 7

```
yum install python36
yum install python36-devel
yum install python36-pip
yum install python36-setuptools
easy_install-3.6 pip
```

to check the pip version:

```
pip3 -V
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-18.0-py3.6.egg/pip (python 3.6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have in this moment install the bs4 with python 3.6.3 on Windows.

```
C:\yourfolderx\yourfoldery>python.exe -m pip install bs4
```

with the syntax like the user post below:

I just successfully installed a package for excel. After installing the python 3.6, you have to download the desired package, then install. For eg,

```
python.exe -m pip download openpyxl==2.1.4

python.exe -m pip install openpyxl==2.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with downloading and installing Python 3.6. Unchecking pip in the installation prevents the issue. So pip is not given in every installation.

Answer (score 0):

There are situations when your `pip` doesn't get downloaded along with python installation. Even your whole script folder can be empty.

You can do so manually as well.

Just head to Command Prompt and type `python -m ensurepip --default-pip` Press Enter.

Make sure that value of path variable is updated.

This will do the Trick

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3.6: No module named ensurepip`

Comment: python3.6: no module named pip

Answer (score 0):

In pyenv I have a case that normal install cause segmentation fault.
to solve this I use the following commands:

```
# create virtaulenv, '--without-pip' is a venv option 
pyenv virtualenv --without-pip  3.6.8 env368
# activate venv
pyenv activate env368
# get pip for 3.6 python version
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py
# for global interpereter
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
# for venv interpreter
python get-pip.py
```

the correct way to get working pip to python3.6 as get from [How to install pip for Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71097683/4159461)

Answer (score -1):

I just successfully installed a package for excel. After installing the `python 3.6`, you have to download the desired package, then install. 
For eg,

1. `python.exe -m pip download openpyxl==2.1.4`
2. `python.exe -m pip install openpyxl==2.1.4`

Answer (score -1):

This what worked for me on Amazon Linux

```
sudo yum list | grep python3
```

sudo yum install python36.x86_64 python36-tools.x86_64

$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8

$ pip -V
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

]$ sudo python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 969kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.3
Successfully installed pip-19.0.3

$ pip -V
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Answer (score -1):

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py

$ python3.6 get-pip.py
```

run the above commands to install for specifically python 3.6.

And installation reboot the terminal and check.

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 21.3.1 from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Python3.6 installs PIP but it is unreachable as it is installed.  There is no code which will invoke it as it is!  I have been at it for more than a week and I read every single advice given, without success!

Finally, I tested going to the pip directory and upgrading the installed version:

```
root@bx:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages # python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

That command created a PIP which now works properly from any location on my FreeBSD server!

Clearly, the tools installed simply do not work, as installed with Python3.6. The only way to run them is to invoke Python and the desired python files as you can see in the command issued.  Once the update is called, however, the new PIP works globally without having to invoke Python3.6...

Answer (score -4):

For python3 it should be pip3

on ubuntu

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: that's not python3.6

Comment: This worked for me with python3.6.9