# Install pip on a fresh compiled python

Tags: python, linux

I have just downloaded the python 3.4 source from the web site and compiled it with `./configure` and `make`. I get a fully functional python.

[Everyone says that pip comes embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304612/how-to-install-pip-on-python-3-6) with python but that is not true if I compile it from source.

On a console I do:

`./python -m pip install numpy`

from the compilation folder, and I get:

> No module named pip

I am on a RHEL7 system and I want to produce a standalone python folder with all the needed modules. My intention is to ship this python folder along with some python software so that I am sure that everything is ok. (Not to rely on others installing all the packages that are needed on a fresh RHEL7 installation)

Comment: I tried [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3] and did not work for me...

Comment: did you try `get-pip.py`? That should work.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I found a pip .whl file in the folder `/Lib/ensurepip/_bundled` I unpacked it under `/Lib` and I had pip working, but it wasn't installing the libraries in the local folder. Instead it tried to install them on the system... Finally I just downloaded with miniconda which worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `pip` try `pip3`. It is python version 3.x and appropriate one for it is pip3 I guess.

Comment: Same history: `No module named pip3`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3 please check this answer, it might help.