# pip not found after installation of python 3.6.4

Tags: python

After i have installed python 3.6.4 pip is not working i have done following procedure :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.98]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python --version
Python 3.6.4

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip --version
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>%PATH%
'F:\app\YASHRAJ\product\11.2.0\grid\bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %PATH%
F:\app\YASHRAJ\product\11.2.0\grid\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;F:\app\YASHRAJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Progr
am Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\
ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program F
iles (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program
Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\YASHRAJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\YASHRAJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Users\YASHRAJ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Try pip3 instead of pip

Comment: try ``python -m pip`` instead of ``pip``

Comment: For windows py -m pip --version, Look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304612/how-to-install-pip-on-python-3-6

Answer (score -1):

If I did not overseen it, you do not have the python 3.6.4 directory in your PATH-variable, only (the old one) python 3.6.32.

Have a look [at this post](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7&ved=2ahUKEwiq3NHP2IbZAhWFC-wKHQUdAPEQFjAAegQIDxAB&usg=AOvVaw0IhuTOMX8NokBAihJv1vrB) how to fix this.

Comment: That does not explain why there is no pip at all (`pip --version 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.)`. Also the output of `python --version` is `Python 3.6.4` indicating that the correct python version is found from the command line

Comment: pip gets installed with python then why it is not working here why it is giving me this error