# pip3 cannot be found after installing python3 and pip3 on a mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, homebrew

python2 is installed on every mac and I installed python3 and used it a lot with the standard libraries. Now I wanted to use pip3 as I did with pip and it says:

`-bash: pip3: command not found`

I downloaded `get-pip.py`found in StackOverflow's answers and with installing it I got:

`Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

In addition to that I tested with `which pip3` and there was *no* output, just the new line with the normal shell. And with `which pip` there is the location output like I expected:

`/usr/local/bin/pip`

I installed python3 with the package and last month I installed `brew`. Maybe this created the conflict because I think I had use `pip3`for some libraries my installation of python3.

(*What possibility do I have to use python3 without having to uninstall python2 and python3 because I need both of them and got the answer that it's no problem to install both of them?*)

Thanks @phd for linking to another question. With

`alias pip3='python3 -m pip'`

in `~/.bash_profile` I can use pip3 as used.

But I do want to know if there is still a place where pip3 is located in python3 and how I can find it?

Thanks a lot.

- macOS 10.12.6 / python 2.7.10 and 3.6.4
- `which python`>> `/usr/bin/python`
- `which python3`>> `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: Maybe `pip3.6` or `pip-3.6`? I'm not familiar with Homebrew or get-pip.

Comment: No but thanks for your fast comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install PIP on Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304612/how-to-install-pip-on-python-3-6)

Comment: Try doing `locate pip | grep /usr/local/bin`...

Comment: @phd I'm sorry, I searched a lot before writing but your link seems to lead to a solution: I created an alias for `pip3` to `python3 -m pip` and now I can work with it as used. Is there no real pip3 in python3?

@l'L'l The command leads to an error with the proposed solution of typing `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`. With no output there immediately is a prompt and your command does still not work. What about the location of pip3?

Is there a possibility to ask additional things to a question at stackoverflow?

Comment: There can be a `pip3` command on your system, but that depends how you installed Python 3 (these days, they tend to come together). So your installation may decided not to install it for you. Your alias, however, is totally fine, as is using `python -m pip3`, so there really is no need for a separate `pip3` command. Or phrased differently: why do you want one if it's already working fine?

Comment: @Evert Thank you. And thank you to all comments.