# pip failling to install for Python 3.7 on MacOs

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm currently working on a Mac with Mojave. I have successfully installed python 3.7 with brew

```
    brew install python3
```

But I have tried several methods to install pip for python 3.7 (installing with get-pip.py, easy_install pip, etc.), which had worked for installing pip in the python 2.7 folder, but not in the python 3.7.

Currently when I call

```
  pip --version
```

I get

```
pip 18.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

And pip3 seems not to exist.

How can I get pip3 installed in the python 3.7 folder? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304612/how-to-install-pip-on-python-3-6

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ensure pip installed for python 3.7, try something like this:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.7 get-pip.py
```

Comment: I already tried this solution but it doesn't seem to work :/ I get a "Successfully installed pip-18.1" message but when I ask "pip --version", I get "pip 18.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)"

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I still don't quite understand what's going on with pip3 in my device, but I found a way to install packages with pip in the right Python version:

```
python3 -m pip install [package]
```

It worked to install numpy which was my primary objective.

Comment: Error: 'No module named pip'

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're using an older version of Brew?

In that case run 
brew postinstall python3

Comment: thanks ! I get a message "The post-install step did not complete successfully" :/

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.x, the command is `pip3`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `pip3 --version` instead of `pip --version`,provided `pip3` was installed successfully.

Check all versions of `pip` installed on your machine using `ls -ltr  /usr/local/bin|grep pip`

Then use the correct executable to query the version.

For example on my machine I get:

```
ls -ltr  /usr/local/bin|grep pip
lrwxr-xr-x  1 abhinav  admin                    33 May  8 03:32 pip3.6 -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin/pip3.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 abhinav  admin                    31 May  8 03:32 pip3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin/pip3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 abhinav  admin                    36 May  8 03:32 pip2.7 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/bin/pip2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 abhinav  admin                    34 May  8 03:32 pip2 -> ../Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/bin/pip2
```

Now if I do

```
pip2 --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)


pip3 --version
pip 18.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

As you can see in the above output, the path shown to you is dependent on where the executable is pointing.

So make sure your `pip` is not pointing to python 2.7

Comment: currently pip3 seems unavailable. When I do "ls -ltr  /usr/local/bin|grep pip" I get "-rwxr-xr-x  1 root      admin       215 29 oct 09:41 pip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root      admin       215 29 oct 09:41 pip2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root      admin       215 29 oct 09:41 pip2.7" and "pip3 --version" returns nothing

Comment: are u able to use `python3` shell?

Comment: ok..are u sure you installed `pip` for `python3`,for @antwane reply you responded it installed correctly .You can check for pip in one of the directories of `$PATH`

Comment: Have you tried creating a virtual environment for python3.7 and using that?