# Pip install always installs to Python 2.7, not Python 3

Tags: python, pip

As explained in title.

Things I've already tried out that didn't work:

- `pip install --upgrade pip`
- `brew postinstall python@3.7`
- `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`, followed by `sudo python3.7 get-pip.py` (the second command doesn't work)

Consulted articles: [How to install PIP on Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304612/how-to-install-pip-on-python-3-6), more

so far, I've been running whatever I've pip installed in a file that contains python packages by running python [filename.py], rather than python3. So it works fine right now but I want to use python3, since python 2.7 is deprecated anyway

Comment: Sometimes `pip` gets locked to a version of python. On my system, for example, `pip` installs for `2.7` and `pip3` for `3.7`. If you've installed python3.x.x then you have `pip3` and you can use that to install packages. Similarly you can use `python3` to run your scripts. Better not to override the system's `pip` because it can break things like `apt` on linux

Comment: Try `python3 -m ensurepip` and then use `pip3 install ...`.

Comment: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override the pip command to Python3.x instead of Python2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938205/how-to-override-the-pip-command-to-python3-x-instead-of-python2-7)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938205/how-to-override-the-pip-command-to-python3-x-instead-of-python2-7/38938246

Comment: @lenz This answers the question, thanks. Can you write a comment so that I can mark your answer as correct?

Comment: sudo pip uninstall pip, followed by sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip, followed by sudo pip -V for checking

Answer (score 2):

You could try using pip3 as that works for python3

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on macOS. In macOS, the commands `python` and `pip` refers to Python 2 and pip 2, because Apple uses Python 2. To use Python 3 and pip 3, use the commands `python3` and `pip3`.

```
pip3 install <yourModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

try installing by `python3 -m pip install <package>`

> Edited this was a workaround though.

for installing the correct pip, you have to remove prev installations.

for that try ``which pip```

try `sudo apt purge pip` or `sudo apt purge python-pip`

also run double-check `sudo apt purge pip3` or `sudo apt purge python3-pip`

Now try `which pip` and `which pip3`
make sure none of them are installed

now `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Answer (score -3):

try:

`sudo apt install python3-pip`

and use

`pip3`

to call pip

Comment: They posted that they tried using `brew postinstall python@3.7` so they are on a Mac. `apt install` won't help.