# Having trouble in installing and importing pyttsx3(text to speech conversion library) in Python VS code

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pyttsx

I am trying this AI assistant Jarvis from a YouTube tutorial and I have to submit it as a final project. In order to start the code, I have to first import `pyttsx3` which is a text-to-speech conversion library in Python. When I write 'pip install pyttsx3' in the terminal of VS Code, it returns back pip not defined. Please guide me here I have no other help.

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure to add your Python to the system PATH?

Comment: can u explain that further?

Comment: Refer [this link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for adding things to PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Try using command line:

`windows_key + r`, and type in `cmd`. Then, 'pip install pyttsx3'.

If you don't have pip (it should come with python, assuming you downloaded python from [the official website](https://www.python.org/)), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304612/how-to-install-pip-on-python-3-6) for reference.

Comment: can i do this in Visual studio code?

Comment: @faryalrizvi it's easier to use PyCharm for that sort of stuff but whatever. Yes, pip should work from the VSC terminal (I just checked with mine), so I think your issue is that you don't have pip at all.

Comment: @faryalrizvi that's good to hear! Consider marking the answer accepted if it helped?