# How to install Pip3 pointing a custom installation of Python3 in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and it has Python 2.7.13 installed. I want to use Python 3 without it colliding with Python 2.7.13.

I've installed and built Python 3 from source and aliased it without an issue. Right now `python` is pointing to `usr/bin/python` which is the system default, and I aliased `python3` to point my custom installation in `~/Python-3.6.3"`.

The next step I'm having problems with is installing `pip3`. If I install it via `apt install python3-pip` I'm afraid it will try to download packages to the older version of Python. Is there a way to install pip3 in the setup I've described and point it to my custom installation of Python 3?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44662468/832230 and then try python -m pip install numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [follow these directions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip) to download a file called get-pip.py.  You simply run this command with the target python installation.

Comment: Worked like a charm.