# Unable to configure pip on user without root access

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5, zlib

I am running below command getting error.

```
python3  /home/user1/get-pip.py --user

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user1/get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "/home/user1/get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

I am unable to configure zlib also on non-root user.
and also I am avoiding to create virtual env.

Comment: You need to have zlib1g-dev installed which without root access won't be possible, kind of stuck... Cant you pip3 install pip--user

Comment: No python3 install pip not working

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/46959072/3581357, might be a duplicate

Comment: there also no solution provided. I think zlib is not installed on Linux at all. as zlib.h is also missing