# How do I install a python module on a different version of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, python-3.6, python-3.5

In brief, I have Python 3.5 but now I also installed 3.6.

I am trying this:

pip3 install web3

This installs web3 only for Python 3.5 (my previous version), I want to make it for 3.6 as well? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to start using virtual environments. Google "python -m venv env" for examples and explainations.

Comment: What's your Operating System,You can use tool like pyenv to switch your current python version

Comment: ubuntu 16.04, I am now trying this...as I want pip to work under 3.6 in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662104/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-6-on-ubuntu-16-10

Comment: You can read this：
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `pip3` still has the path to Python 3.5 in it, so that is what gets run. You can also run pip as a module using the specific Python that you want.

> python3.6 -m pip ...

Alternatively, copy `pip3` to `pip3.6` then modify it to use python3.6.

Comment: OK, your solution works as it finds web3 now...but I'm getting "fatal error can't find python.h" when it proceeds to installing any package...maybe it still acts as if this is the old version.

Comment: How did you install it, and what OS is it? That looks like you may be missing a "dev" package for it.